# Regular expression to match multiple occurrences of characters between delimiters

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to use NSRegularExpression to find multiple occurrences of substrings that are delimited by a pair of % characters, for example if I want to extract "%FirstOccurence%`enter code here`" as a substring from the following:

```
"stuff %FirstOccurence% more stuff"
```

Then I can do this:

```
NSString* const pattern = @"[%].+[%]";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [testData length]);
NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [regex firstMatchInString:testData options:0 range: range];
```

However if the string contains something like this:

```
 "stuff %FirstOccurence% more stuff %Second Occurrence% yet more stuff"
```

Then my regex will match this: `"%FirstOccurence% more stuff %Second Occurrence%"` i.e. the NSTextCheckingResult will contain one range.

What should the regex/code be to make the NSTextCheckingResult contain two ranges of `%FirstOccurence%`  and `%Second Occurrence%` rather than the one larger range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to be calling matchesInString:options:range: which returns all the matching results.

```
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRegularExpression